# ListView doesn't work in my controller class Android

Tags: java, android, onitemclicklistener

I have a problem with my app. I have implemented mvc design pattern with a view and a controller. The controller have OnClickListener methods (4 buttons and a listview). The problem is that when the activities begins the buttons listeners responds but the listview is completely stationnaire, I can't click on and I cant't scroll throught the list. 
I show you my code. I hope any help please.

all_products.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/myLayout">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="389dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Mapa" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Lista" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Buscador" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="Más" />
```

The Main Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.all_products);


   final MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
   final MyView myView = new MyView(this);
   MyController myController = new MyController(this, myModel, myView);

   ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
   container.addView(myView);
   container.addView(myController); 

   Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
   String[] array=b.getStringArray("listaEventos");

   //A continuación, generamos los distintos valores que ocuparán el LinearLayout, concretamente
   //las categorías de los eventos.
   String[] values = new String[] { "Actividades vacacionales", "Aire libre y excursiones", "Cine",
    "Conferencias y otros", "Congresos y jornadas", "Cursos y talleres", "Deporte", "Escénicas",
    "Exposiciones", "Ferias", "Fiestas y festivales", "Música", "Viajes", "Otras" };

   //Llamamos al adapter personalizado para mostrar la vista.
   MyListCategoryArrayAdapter adapter = new MyListCategoryArrayAdapter(this, values, array);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
```

}

The Controller

```
public class MyController extends RelativeLayout{

 public MyController(Activity activity, 
      final MyModel myModel, final MyView myView) {
super(activity, null);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
          (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService   
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.all_products, this);

final Button button0 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Boton0", "Boton0");

    }
});

final Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Boton1", "Boton1");

    }
 }); 

final Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Boton2", "Boton2");

    }
}); 

final Button button3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Boton3", "Boton3");

    }
}); 

ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, 
            View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("Pulsando en lista", "Pulsando en lista");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why you are doing this ?

Comment: to implement mvc design pattern. I know there is other ways to do this, but I have to do with the controller.

Comment: Not to pile on more, but you can think of an Activity as a controller.  You are actually making the controller out of a view, which is kind up backwards to me.